# What can we say about the relative velocity of two particles if the separation between them remains constant?

Tags: velocity, relative-motion

Can we say that the **relative velocity is zero** between the two particles if the separation between them remains constant? If not, why? Please explain with example(s).

Comment: We can say the relative velocity is perpendicular to the separation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the relative velocity ($v_2 - v_1$) may change while the separation ($|r_2 - r_1|$) remains constant.

Consider one particle tracing a circular path around another stationary particle -  like an orbit.  The velocity of the second is constantly changing relative to the first while the separation remains constant.